# Calling clone methods in a class hierarchy

Tags: java, class, clone, hierarchy

So, I have three classes (Person, Employee, and Manager). Employee extends Person, and Manager extends Employee...

I am trying to create a clone method for each class. Person is easy, because I can just create a new Person with all the same data members.

```
    public Object clone(){
    Person temp = new Person(new String(name), new String(address), new  String(phoneNumber));
    return temp;
}
```

Employee is possible, because I can create a new Employee using the super's get methods to initialize those data members as well as the new ones in Employee.

```
    public Object clone(){
    Employee temp = new Employee(new String(super.getName()), new String(super.getAddress()),
            new String(super.getPhoneNumber()), salary);
    temp.hireDate = new Date(hireDate.getTime()); //Argument for new Date in milliseconds
    return temp;
}
```

But, for Manager I have no way of getting the data members from Person...

```
    public Object clone(){
    Object temp = (Manager)super.clone();
    ((Manager)temp).annualBonus = annualBonus;
    return temp;
}
```

What I wanted to do was call each super.clone() method in each class' clone method, but it will not allow me to downcast, such as calling the clone of Person, and down-casting the result to Employee...

Comment: There is no reason to clone a string.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()

Comment: But then how do I copy the strings from the Person object to the Manager object?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Java Deep-Cloning library. I've used it in the past and works well enough. It's java library which deep-clones objects. You even don't have top use the Cloneable interface.

```
Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
YourClass clone = cloner.deepClone(someObjectOfTypeYourClass);
```

Code can be found at http://code.google.com/p/cloning/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions, but I got it figured out...

Since I can't downcast Person, I need to construct an Employee by calling the get methods in Person..

```
Object temp = new Employee(super.getName(), super.getAddress(), super.getPhoneNumber(), salary);
```